# How do I load an excel workbook into its own instance AND keep it isolated in its own instance

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

Context: Windows 10 Desktop Edition of Excel

Using the command line switch `excel.exe /x filename.xlsx` I can open an excel workbook in its own process BUT how do I prevent subsequently opened workbooks from being added to this process/instance?

Described in another way: I want to have all mine and my clients workbooks open in the usual way in a single process/instance BUT have one particular workbook be kept separate so as not to contaminate OR be contaminated by crashing of the other instance.

I'm looking for a solution that will be transparent to regular, everyday users of my spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you mean that once you have opened a new process with `excel.exe /x`, then later invocations will use this one process?

Comment: No, quite the opposite, I want that process to be blocked off to further excel files being added to it

Comment: That's what I asked. I tested this myself: `excel.exe /x` followed by double-click another file, will effectively use the same running process.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this myself and indeed `excel.exe /x` followed by double-click
on another spreadsheet, will effectively use the same running process.

I can only think of two methods:

1. Install two different versions of Office, for example Office 2019 and 2016,
   set the latest version 2019 as the default handler for spreadsheets,
   but use version 2016 for your own spreadsheet.
2. Create a virtual machine, install inside Office and your spreadsheet,
   then work inside it.

Comment: I suppose both of those would technically be "solutions" to the problem but I am looking for something lighter-weight (less intrusive to the users normal workflow).

Comment: For another "solution", you need to isolate one `excel.exe` from the rest of Windows. You could try a product such as Sandboxie, but that would take some fiddling.

Comment: Actually, Windows 10 (latest version) has its own built-in Sandbox environment (called "Windows Sandbox"), but I'm trying to find a solution that would be transparent to ordinary unsophisticated users of the program/spreadsheet.

Comment: The Windows Sandbox is all or nothing, not side by side like Sandboxie. Everything would be transparent once you set it up. Question: Why is this isolation required?

Comment: Good question. I intend for my workbook to be something that is open (without closing) for pretty much the entire workday as the user keeps coming back to the application to do their work. Main reason: I don't want the other workbooks to crash and then cause my workbook to crash and perhaps get corrupted with them.

Comment: The simple solution is to add more user account(s).

Comment: Do you mean Office 365 user accounts OR actual windows user accounts to log in and out of?

Comment: Windows accounts would separate the documents and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Ablebits link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-workbooks-separate-windows-instances/), but here are a few of those suggestions across Office versions:

- Right-click Excel icon in task bar and select Excel - or however
  Excel shows up for you
- Press and hold Alt while double-clicking the
  required spreadsheet, then confirm
- Wheel-click the Excel icon in the task bar